# Every Cayley graph is vertex transitive

Tags: graph-theory, cayley-graphs

I cannot come up with a proof of the following statement (which is true according to wikipedia):
Every Cayley graph is vertex-transitive.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** For every $g$ in the group the map $v\mapsto gv$ is a graph isomorphism of the Cayley graph.

Comment: thanks, that was sufficient!